# apt-get broke after trying to install wine

Tags: apt, wine, dependencies

I'm a new Linux user. I use Kali Linux and tried to install wine via:

```
sudo apt-get install wine winetricks
```

This, however, didn't work as there were some errors. After that, I cannot install, update or do anything apt-get related. Running apt-get gives this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Running apt-get install -f makes it try to install wine 1.6, but it fails at that. Here is the initial output for this command:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libp11-kit-gnome-keyring wine1.6 wine1.6-i386
Suggested packages:
  dosbox:any winbind
Recommended packages:
  fonts-droid wine-gecko2.21 wine-mono0.0.8
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libp11-kit-gnome-keyring wine1.6 wine1.6-i386
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 283 not upgraded.
20 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/16.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 120 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I cannot install anything else, as this wine dependency error gets in the way. Running apt-get clean does nothing on the matter. How can I solve this? Either by removing wine once and for all or by installing wine nicely, whatever works and doesn't break the system is fine for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what did you give after the last statement? Did you continue installing? Did you give yes for this ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping.
I gave a no. But giving a yes stills causes errors, as follows http://paste.ubuntu.com/18008432/

I had to paste it in that link since the text was too long.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question is not about Ubuntu. Please flag your question to be closed or to be migrated to UNIX and Linux Stack Exchange. Please do not cross-post unless you delete your question.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of struggle I solved it.
I had to remove the dependencies via dpkg -r

The full set of actions were:

```
sudo dpkg -r libwine:i386
sudo dpkg -r wine1.6-i386
sudo dpkg -r kali-linux-full
sudo dpkg -r regripper
sudo dpkg -r sqldict
sudo dpkg -r ollydbg
sudo dpkg -r wine
```

After that, everything went back to normal.
Hope this helps someone helps struggling with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use aptitude.

```
sudo aptitude install wine winetricks
```

It is a bit more verbose and will try and try and try.